# Wifi Direct print in application

Tags: java, android, printing, wifi

I read a lot of questions about WIFI direct print, but no really accepting answer. And maybe there are recents evolution ...

Thats why I ask the mine :
In my application, I need to print a pdf file I created. How to direct-wifi-print it, without being connected to internet or any other network (no cloud printing), except the printer's one ?

I would like to do it with a button that immediatly launches the printing on the (appaired) printer.

I didn't buy the printer, so if someone has a solution with a specific printer, I'd appreciate to know how, and which one I had to buy.
Tks for your advices

Comment: You would need to find a printer manufacturer that has a printer that offers WiFiDirect printing, has released an app for Android that either offers a printing API or offers an Android 4.4 `PrintService` implementation, and has that app written such that it will use the WiFiDirect protocol. None of that has much to do with SO -- you'll need to conduct some online searches, call some manufacturers, etc.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Its exactly what I hoped someone could tell me here : a printer model, with its code to direct print without 3rd party application. Thanks for answer, I ll continue searching.

Answer (score 0):

Some printer manufactures like canon, sumsung or hp has manufactured printers that offers WiFiDirect printing. And they also released apps that compatible to their devices. You just need to make sure your mobile terminals and the printer are in the same wifi lan. Then the app will identify that printer and you will easily print docs or pics on your mobile terminals.